# How to suppress CatBoost iteration results?

Tags: python, catboost

I am trying to use CatBoost to fit a binary model. When I use the following code, I thought `verbose=False` can help to suppress the iteration logs. But it didn't. Is there a way to avoid print the iterations?

```
model=CatBoostClassifier(iterations=300, depth=6, learning_rate=0.1, 
loss_function='Logloss',
         rsm = 0.95, 
         border_count = 64, 
         eval_metric =  'AUC', 
         l2_leaf_reg= 3.5, 
         one_hot_max_size=30, 
         use_best_model = True,
         verbose=False,
         random_seed = 502)

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
     eval_set=(X_test_filtered, y_test_num),   
     verbose = False,
     plot=True)
```

[image]

Comment: does `verbose=None` work?

Comment: IMO, it is a bit of a mess, since they have at least 3 (or even 4) parameters controlling verbosity in different ways (and defined at different stages, e.g. parameters from `.fit()` precede those from the constructor) and there is a dedicated function to resolve those: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/be72d53a1cb72e4827c4ac01623a28a30dca084a/catboost/python-package/catboost/core.py#L117

Comment: `logging_level='Silent'`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

CatBoost has several parameters to control verbosity. Those are `verbose`, `silent` and `logging_level`.

By default logging is verbose, so you see loss value on every iteration.
If you want to see less logging, you need to use one of these parameters.
It's not allowed to set two of them simultaneously.

`silent` has two possible values - `True` and `False`.

`verbose` can also be `True` and `False`, but it also can be an integer. If it is an integer N, then logging will be printed out each N-th iteration.

`logging_level` can be `'Silent'`, `'Verbose'`, `'Info'` and `'Debug'`:

- `'Silent'` means no output to stdout (except for important warnings)
  and is same as `silent=True` or `verbose=False`.
- `'Verbose'` is the
  default logging mode. It's the same as `verbose=True` or
  `silent=False`.
- `'Info'` prints out the trees that are selected on
  every iteration.
- `'Debug'` prints a lot of debug info.

There are two places where you can use these parameters.
The first one is model creation. The second one is fitting of the created model.
If you have used a parameter when creating the model then it will be used during fitting if no parameter in fit function is specified.

If you use parameter in fit function then the mode selected by this parameter will be used.

In your case it looks like you have encountered a bug. The next time you see some bug, the best thing is to report to CatBoost team using issues on the GitHub page. This bug should have already been fixed, so try upgrading to the latest version or build code from source.

Comment: Anna, is there a way to disable a GUI (ie, accuracy chart, controls, etc)? It's still shown in my ipython no matter what verbose level I set...

Comment: Set parameter plot=False

Comment: thanks, already figured it out ) I forgot I was using plot=True at all )

Answer (score 8):

Set `metric_period=100`. It should work.

Comment: This works! But, as per the documentation, metric_period is "The frequency of iterations to calculate the values of objectives and metrics. The value should be a positive integer." The default value is 1. That means if I set it to 100, the evaluation will happen only after 100 iterations which is okay. But, not sure if that has any different impact or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **cross_val_score**, it will keep printing the iterations since you won't be using **model.fit**.

As a workaround, you need to pass the parameters to the fit method of the estimator using **fit_params**.

```
model = CatBoostClassifier()
params={'verbose': False} 

cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=42)
scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, scoring='r2', cv=cv, fit_params=params)
```

I know you did not use cross validation in your code, but it was my case and when I finally figured it out, I felt like I needed to post here in case someone might be looking for exact same thing.